# AWS Amplify GraphQL CreateOrUpdate / Upsert mutation

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

Minor newbie with GraphQL so I'm a little bit lost here. How would I go about creating a CreateOrUpdate mutation/resolver for a model on AWS Amplify?

I'm running a lambda function after every user auth to hit a third party API and pull back relevant data to that user. The entities that come back may already be stored but related to another user. I'm assuming there's a better way than attempting to Create, catching an error and then attempting to Fetch & Update with the new user appended to the `users` field?!

```
type Event
@model
@auth(rules: [
  {allow: public, provider: apiKey, operations: [read, create, update, delete]}
  {allow: owner, ownerField: "users"}
])
@key(fields: ["venue", "date"])
{
  id: ID!
  venue: String!
  date: AWSDate!
  ref: String!
  users: [String]!
}
```

Any help massively appreciated (even just good resources to read up on writing resolvers - looking at the generated `Mutation.updateEvent.req.vtl` file for inspiration is a bit intimidating)

Comment: Not sure I understand but you need to query and update the db in your lambda trigger right? If you already have setup the lambda you can query your Api by sending requests to the graphql endpoint and depending on your validations you can also send mutations as post requests. but I may be misunderstanding something.

Comment: I have the exact same query - did you have any luck finding a solution @alex

Comment: Unfortunately nothing straightforward @BenSouthall - I ended up with a `createOrUpdate` JS function that essentially tried a create, if data.errors.length > 1 then it tries an update instead.
I am calculating my own UUID IDs first so I'm not relying on Amplify GraphQL primary keys which makes it easier to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the generated resolver for `update` mutation.

Just copy the content of the autogenerated resolvers and make some changes.

File name may look like this:

```
<project-root>/amplify/backend/api/<api-name>/build/resolvers/<TypeName>.<FieldName>.<req/res>.vlt
```

To override, copy this file to:

```
<project-root>/amplify/backend/api/<api-name>/resolvers/<TypeName>.<FieldName>.<req/res>.vlt
```

For example: `amplify/backend/api/blog/build/resolvers/Mutation.updatePost.req.vtl`

Then remove these line:

```
## Begin - key condition **
#if( $ctx.stash.metadata.modelObjectKey )
  #set( $keyConditionExpr = {} )
  #set( $keyConditionExprNames = {} )
  #foreach( $entry in $ctx.stash.metadata.modelObjectKey.entrySet() )
    $util.qr($keyConditionExpr.put("keyCondition$velocityCount", {
  "attributeExists": true
}))
    $util.qr($keyConditionExprNames.put("#keyCondition$velocityCount", "$entry.key"))
  #end
  $util.qr($ctx.stash.conditions.add($keyConditionExpr))
#else
  $util.qr($ctx.stash.conditions.add({
  "id": {
      "attributeExists": true
  }
}))
#end
```

That part of vtl code checks that the id on update mutation should exists.